# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast ARGV

Tags: c, argv

This is the warning I get.

```
copyit.c: In function ‘main’:
copyit.c:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
copyit.c:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

The lines of code that this corresponds to are the ones that begin with pointers (*).

```
char source[128],target[128],buffer[512];

if(argc==3) {
*source = argv[1];
*target = argv[2];
}
```

I just want to assign those two things so I can pass them from the command line like that and I can then use them in my handle (ex: inhandle=open(source,O_RDONLY);
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use strcpy() from string.h:

```
strcpy(source,argv[1]);
strcpy(target,argv[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that but strangely I only got a warning for the first one that said this: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
Thoughts?

Comment: Include the header `<string.h>`.

Comment: Include string.h at the top

Comment: The problem with this solution is if the user passes a command line argument larger than 127 characters you've just had a buffer overflow. You can use strncpy to stop the buffer overflow but now your left with a program that will fail if the path passes in is larger than 127 characters

Comment: No strcpy does not check anything.

Answer (score 4):

argv is an array of string pointers. You should just change `source` and `target` to `char *` or `const char *` instead of arrays and change the code to

```
source = argv[3];
target = argv[4];
```

That will make it work. It will also prevent a buffer overflow had you copied the strings into the arrays. It would also mean your app will handle long file paths.

Comment: @haccks: Read the answer more carefully. He suggested changing the declarations of `source` and `target` so they're both `char*`, *not* arrays. It's a good idea, and probably the best answer here; there's probably no need to copy the array contents.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Sorry. I missed that.